# Xavier initialisation vs He initialisation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, inceptionresnetv2

After reading the famous paper, [Delving Deep into Rectifiers: Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf), I understand two things:-

- He initilization borrows on the benefits of Xavier initialization except that the latter expected a linear activation and the prior accounts for ReLU non-linear activation. Infact they differ just by a factor of `sqrt(2)`.
- All the fuss is about layers having 0 mean and 1 std achieved by Xavier initialization but when ReLU is used the negative is clipped and so mean rises and thus the He initialzation introduces the sqrt(2) correction term which helps train a lot better.

So my question is as about the basic ResBlock which almost uninamously implemented as follows,

```
class ResBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,in_c):
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_c,in_c, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_c,in_c, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=True)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2, inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x):

        identity = x

        out = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
        #out = F.leaky_relu_(out, negative_slope=0.2)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = out + identity

        return out
```

Note that `conv2` is not followed by ReLU and only `Conv1` is followed by ReLU. Thus `conv2` should have Xavier init and `Conv1` have He init. But the dominant practice is to use He init for both. Isn't this wrong?

***---EDIT---***

Alternatively, we can have `conv2` have He initialization with 'leak parameter, a=1' and `Conv1` have He initialization with 'leak parameter a=0'. The leak parameter is used to calculate the appropriate gain. But the dominant practice is to use He init for both with leak parameter set to 0. Isn't this wrong?

The 'leak parameter a' is the negative slope of the ReLU activation used after the conv layer. Check [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=kaiming_normal_#torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_) for more information.

Thankyou